# Pandas - select all rows between two values when a string is a match

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'fruit': ['apple', 'pear', 'peach'] * 5, 'values': np.random.randint(0,1000,15)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 = {'fruit': ['apple', 'pear', 'peach'] * 2, 'min': [43, 196, 143, 174, 510, 450], 'max': [120, 310, 311, 563, 549, 582]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

I'd like to select all the rows in `df` with matching `fruit` to `df2` *and* `values` between `min` and `max`.

I'm trying something like:

```
df.loc[df['fruit'].isin(df2['fruit'])].loc[df['values'].between(df2['min'], df2['max'])]
```

But predictably this is returning a ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects.

**EDIT**: you'll notice that `fruit` is repeated in `df2`. This is intentional. I still am trying to grab the rows between `min` and `max` as above, but I don't just want to collapse the fruits and take the rows between the absolute `min` and `max`.

For example, in `df1` where `fruit` == 'apple' I'd like all the rows with `values` between 43-120 and 174-563.

Comment: Merge returns duplicates where there is duplicates. So the below answer should work. If it doesn't, please post a dataframe without random values and post the expected output so we can be clear.

Comment: good point, missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df3 = df.merge(df2, on='fruit', how='inner') # Thanks for Henry Ecker for suggesting inner join
df3 = df3.loc[(df3['min'] < df3['values']) & (df3['max'] > df3['values'])]
df3
```

**Output**

```
    fruit   values  min max
3   apple   883     467 947
6   apple   805     467 947
9   apple   932     467 947
11  peach   331     307 618
12  apple   665     467 947
```

**If we don't want `min` and `max` col in output**

```
df3 = df3.drop(columns=['min', 'max'])
df3
```

**Output**

```
    fruit   values
3   apple   883
6   apple   805
9   apple   932
11  peach   331
12  apple   665
```

Comment: The merged table will end up with NaNs where there are values in `df1` but not in `df2`. Maybe inner merge here since we're looking for values in both frames?